# Excel String Split and Sum

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a string like below

```
S2/3/5
```

I want to get the SUM of 2, 3, 5.

Is there any way I could split the string and get the sum of only the integers? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slightly shorter, though still not elegant:

```
=SUM(MID(A1,2,1),MID(A1,4,1),MID(A1,6,1))
```

or even

```
=MID(A1,2,1)+MID(A1,4,1)+MID(A1,6,1)
```

The following is interesting, but a little odd. In Excel 2010 (don't know about other versions):

- click into the cell where you need the result to appear
- on the Formulas tab click *Define Name* towards the centre
- Type a Name such as Calc (no spaces allowed)
- Enter the following into the Refers To box, assuming that the expression is in A1

Enter:

```
=EVALUATE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,2,255),"/","+"))
```

Press OK, then in the current cell, type `=Calc`.

I should stress that I am not recommending this as it (EVALUATE) is an undocumented feature, and perhaps will fail in other, or newer, versions of Excel. Interesting though.

Comment: haha replace `/` with `+` nice idea :D +

Answer (score 1):

I'm not the expert, but if all your strings look like that you can then do:

```
=SUM(VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,2),1)),VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,4),1)),VALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(A1,6),1)))
```

Maybe someone will post more elegant way :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula.

```
=SUM(SPLIT(A1,"/"))
```

Comment: `SPLIT` is not a valid Excel function

Comment: Worked perfectly in Google Spreadsheet.